# JS: How to keep the space in URL

Tags: javascript, angular, url

I'm using Angular 4 and in my service I have a delete api with 2 strings as params like this

```
this.http.delete(this.url + 'api/v1/ReportingService/collectionID/'+ '45902' +'/'+'ReportName/' + 'my report 2012:21:24.810419' + '/DeleteReport', { headers: this.headers })
    .map(this.extractResponse)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Report name param is having spaces. I'm aware that a url cannot have spaces. When I call the api spaces are getting replaced by %20. Thus I tried replacing spaces with '' and spaces with 20, both the ways. But I have to retain spaces since report name would be stored in the database with a space so I must have a space in the api.
How to resolve this?

Comment: You will have to decode it in the backend/API side of the application. Or send this parameters in a post request, in the body, instead of using get.

Comment: you cant, you either need to use the code `%20` or use something like an underscore

Answer (score 0):

The percent encoding is part of [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) which describes the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) syntax. You need to live with it and decode the string on the server side before you insert it into the database.

If the server side is implemented using JavaScript then you can use the [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function on the string.

```
decodeURI('a%20b%20c') // result: 'a b c'
```

All server side languages will have a similar function, for example:

- .NET : [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Java : [java.net.URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)
- PHP : [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)
- Python : [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)
- Ruby : [CGI::unescape](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescape)